# Laptop lcd cable serial number

Tags: hardware-rec

I'm having a hard time searching for a lcd cable replacement for a asus' laptop.
Which serial number should i use for searching?

Here's the foto of the cable:

[image]

Comment: You are not looking for a SERIAL number. You are probably looking for a part number.

Answer (score 1):

DDKJ3ALC000 is the part identifier. See [here](http://www.samsungusbcable.com/product.php?id=5781).

Comment: [What about this one?](http://www.asusparts.eu/Asus-14G22100110U) will this one work too @david-schwartz?